# Axios POST in crete-react-app with PHP API works on localhost but no data goes to live mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, axios

http://www.hakvik.se/react/#/contact
I have googled for several days without success. No cors problems. Everything looks okay in console but nothing goes to db table on my live host when I am trying to post data from my contact form to mysql db. When I change details in Headers and axios call to locahost it works as expected.

Below is the relevant code, please tell me if you need additional code to see the problem!

I have used create-react-app.

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let config = {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://www.hakvik.se',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
  }
};

// axios.post('http://127.0.0.1/myProjects/react-refactored-with-redux/src/api/index.php/?/user',
axios.post('http://www.hakvik.se/react/#/src/api/index.php/?/user',
  querystring.stringify({
    fname: this.state.fname,
    lname: this.state.lname,
    mail: this.state.mail,
    msg: this.state.msg
  }),
  config
);
```

Comment: Does your api server accept `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` header? Doesn't it expect `application/json` instead?

Comment: I tried replace to application/json but the same result = nothing goes to db and no error in console.

Comment: You should be looking for a bug at the server side. Check if your endpoint can parse data that you're sending.

Comment: Also what response code/message are you getting from the server?

Comment: Thank you for support! The form is here: http://www.hakvik.se/react/#/contact

On localhost everything okay. Perhaps something with querystring, it looks like nothing is sent -but only live.